# UIPageViewController does not release the at last displayed dialog

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am presenting a simple UIPageViewController and adding some really simple and stupid child view controllers to it. When the UIPageViewController gets dismissed I am disposing all child view controllers, the ones currently not displayed (listed in ChildViewControllers) and the one displayed (listed in ViewControllers). The not displayed ones get released, the displayed one gets not.

I have broken this down to a simple failing test, so I am sure it's not about the content of the child view controllers or some other issues around that. I have no idea what is retaining it.

Sample:

Master (presented)

```
public class MasterDialog : UIPageViewController
{
    public event EventHandler OnDialogClosed;

    private UIBarButtonItem _backButton;

    public MasterDialog() :  base(
        UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle.Scroll, 
        UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientation.Horizontal, 
        UIPageViewControllerSpineLocation.None, 
        25)
    {
        _backButton = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Cancel);
        _backButton.Clicked += Close;

        NavigationItem.SetLeftBarButtonItem(_backButton, false);
    }

    public override void ViewDidDisappear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewDidDisappear(animated);

        OnDialogClosed(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    private void Close(object sender, EventArgs arguments)
    {
        _backButton.Clicked -= Close;

        NavigationController.DismissViewController(true, null);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);

        Console.WriteLine("Master disposed");
    }
}
```

Master Data Source

```
public class DataSource : UIPageViewControllerDataSource
{
     public override UIViewController GetPreviousViewController(
        UIPageViewController pageViewController, UIViewController referenceViewController)
     {
         var detail = (DetailDialog)referenceViewController;

         if (detail.Page - 1 == 0)
             return null;

         return GetViewController(detail.Page - 1);
     }

     public override UIViewController GetNextViewController(
        UIPageViewController pageViewController, UIViewController referenceViewController)
     {
         var detail = (DetailDialog)referenceViewController;

         return GetViewController(detail.Page + 1);
     }

     public UIViewController GetViewController(int page)
     {
         return new DetailDialog(page);
     }
}
```

Detail (Child)

```
public class DetailDialog : UITableViewController
{
    public int Page { get; private set; }

    public DetailDialog(int page) : base(UITableViewStyle.Plain)
    {
        Page = page;
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        Console.WriteLine("Detail init: " + Page + " / " + GetHashCode());

        var label = new UILabel();
        label.Text = "#" + Page;
        label.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center;
        label.Frame = new System.Drawing.RectangleF(0, 100, 320, 50);
        label.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green;

        Add(label);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);

        Console.WriteLine("Detail disposed: " + Page + " / " + GetHashCode());
    }
}
```

The opening dialog (starting point)

```
    public class StartDialog : UIViewController
    {
        private DataSource _dataSource;
        private MasterDialog _master;

        public StartDialog()
        {
            Title = "WTF";
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            var button = new UIButton(UIButtonType.Custom);
            button.SetTitle("Open", UIControlState.Normal);
            button.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green;
            button.Frame = new System.Drawing.RectangleF(20, 150, 280, 44);

            Add(button);

            button.TouchDown += OpenMasterDialog;
        }

        private void OpenMasterDialog(object sender, EventArgs arguments)
        {
            _dataSource = new DataSource();

            _master = new MasterDialog();
            _master.DataSource = _dataSource;
            _master.OnDialogClosed += HandleOnDialogClosed;

            _master.SetViewControllers(
                new [] { _dataSource.GetViewController(1) }, 
                UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, 
                false, 
                null
            );

            NavigationController.PresentViewController(
                new UINavigationController(_master), 
                true, 
                null
            );
        }

        private void HandleOnDialogClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _dataSource.Dispose();
            _dataSource = null;

            Console.WriteLine("Before: " + _master.ChildViewControllers.Length +
                "/" + _master.ViewControllers.Length + ")");

            var childs = _master
                .ChildViewControllers.ToList()
                    .Union(_master.ViewControllers);

            foreach (UIViewController child in childs)
            {
                child.RemoveFromParentViewController();
                child.Dispose();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("After: " + _master.ChildViewControllers.Length + 
                "/" + _master.ViewControllers.Length + ")");

            _master.OnDialogClosed -= HandleOnDialogClosed;
            _master.Dispose();
            _master = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Out of curiosity have you tried `sgen` and `sgen`+`newrefcount` for garbage collection ? Also do you have this in a repo/.zip somewhere ? I might have some *free* time tonight to check this (and satisfy another part of my curiosity).

Comment: Hi @poupou, I haven't tried any other than the default configuration for garbage collection as I am fighting memory leaking for weeks now and don't want to face any silly side effects because of experimental stuff (if you would state it's safe to use, I though would give it a try). You can download the project here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9y22lsw2fityr2r/Xamarin.iOS.UIPageViewControllerMemory.zip

Let me know if you could find a minute to look at it and if it's a bug or just me who's wrong :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding your code/intent but in this case it seems to me that everything is *almost* fine. Anyway here's my findings...

```
Detail disposed: 1 / 36217954
After: 0/1)
```

Line #2 shows `/1` which I assume to be the issue. This is normal because you're **re**-surfacing the view controller, IOW the code:

```
_master.ViewControllers.Length
```

calls the `viewControllers` selector on the `UIPageViewController`. That returns: "*The view controllers displayed by the page view controller.*" which is still `DetailDialog` at that point (even if `master` is not displayed anymore).

This is not Xamarin specific, an ObjC application would return the same (native) instance at that same point of time.

That's explained - but it still not freed later, why ?

Under the **[new `Dispose` semantics](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/376/call-for-beta-testers-for-new-dispose-semantics)** the managed object is kept, after `Dispose`, as long as the native side requires it (but without a native reference so it can be natively released and, subsequently, released on the managed side).

In this case the lifecycle of the **native** object is not yet over (i.e. iOS still has reference to it) so it remains *alive* on the managed side.

```
        _master.Dispose();
        _master = null;
```

This removes the **managed** references to `_master` but again (same as above) it won't be *freed* (and neither will be `DetailDialog`) as long as the native `_master` instance is used (with native references).

So who got a reference to `_master` ?

```
      NavigationController.PresentViewController(
            new UINavigationController(_master),
```

^ That creates a `UINavigationController` and as long as it's alive the there are references to the others.

When I dispose of the `UINavigationController` (I kept it in a field) then the Master* and Detail* instances disappear from HeapShot.

```
    _nav.Dispose();
    _nav = null;
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort! I am aware of the situation of GC vs. RC, that is why I am reconstructing my whole application to get freed what ever is opened. At this point I don't get rid of the last detail dialog (your assumption here was right), and it sounds logical to remove the navigation controller, too. But I am not getting it to work, disposing the navigation controller in my HandleOnDialogClosed doesn't change anything. Could you post your modified method, so I can test with it? Thanks.

Comment: Sure https://gist.github.com/spouliot/72fd254a1d1223b0a5a0 If you open/close with HeapShot you won't see DetailDialog (after a Open/Close). You can use the filter (after taking a shot) to confirm it. If you uncomment the two lines (Dispose/null) then HeapShot will report it.

Comment: Okay, I just updated to 7.0.6 and now that nasty DetailDialog is gone. Before: no way. Unfortunately I do not remember what version I was running before. One last question: for what reason did you put the navigation button in a private field? Is that useful regarding GC?

Comment: That was for testing with **newrefcount** - it crashed otherwise (there's a bug).

Comment: Glad I didn't try it anyway :D Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: FWIW it's fixed (not yet released) and, like I suspected, it did solve the issue without requiring any code change.